# How to stop monitor speakes from humming?

Tags: audio, hdmi, speakers, noise, pulse-audio

I have monitor with internal speakers connected via hdmi cable. While booting it hums at annoying, but bearable level. After that, when I for example start youtube video in browser, the hum becomes louder and persists even after closing the browser. Note, that only noise (if anything) is actually going to the monitor speakers and sound is redirected to my headphones via integrated sound card and analog cable. How can I make it stop, make it stay on that bearable level, or at least further debug it?

This condition can also be triggered by issuing the `pactl exit` command, which makes me think, that pulseaudio is somehow involved, or at least, that it's solvable in software. I tried adding `blacklist snd_hda_codec_hdmi` into my /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file, but that made no difference.

When I tried to get frequency spectrum of the sound with my phone, I got single peak just under 500Hz. From that I assume that it's not any interference with the power supply, but I don't know enough about audio to say that for sure. Both my computer and my monitor are connected to the same extension cord.

---

[Edit]

Manipulating the Master volume via `alsamixer` has no effect on the noise volume.

Comment: Speaking as an audio engineer who knows absolutely nothing about nix or pulseaudio, that sounds to me like a 'howl round' condition, a feedback loop - something is feeding a very low audio signal [which could technically include theoretical but not actual silence] which is feeding itself back to source, then round in a circle. At 500Hz, you can pretty much eliminate any earth/ground issues, that would be at 50 or 60Hz, depending on country.

Comment: @Tetsujin Since selecting "mute" option in my monitor settings makes the humming louder, do you suppose, that having some connected audio circuit might reduce the amount of noise? Pulseaudio might disconnect all other sources when sending signal to my headphones and by that also disconnect electronics acting as some kind of buffer for the noise.

Comment: I'm also an (ex) audio engineer, and I agree that this is most certainly not a computer or software issue.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 It's quite probable that the fundamental issue lies in hardware. Bearing that in mind, I see it as irrefutable, that the issue is heavily affected by software. I admit that the hum is probably generated by amplification of noise in hardware, but that doesn't explain why launching or stopping certain software amplifies that hum (or affects it at all for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what monitor you have but you may be able to set the audio out from HDMI to analog from your PC, and bypass monitor all together.

Otherwise I suggest isolating the power sources (could be a ground loop, but 500mhz seems high for that). Can you control hum from PC volume control? Try to get them off the same outlet if you can and try that... if the PC doesn't influence the hum, switch off HDMI audio.

I love the idea of everything coming from the HDMI cable, but it's not clean as we'd like sometimes, better to separate A / V then.

Comment: I clarified my question a bit. I am not playing any audio from the monitor, nor do I want to. The monitor does actually have a mute option, but that makes the hum louder. The volume control does not affect the hum. As I mentioned in my question I have both PC and monitor plugged in the same extension cord.